# Specifying time duration in java

Tags: java, date, time, calendar, duration

I'm developing an application where the user sends a time duration in this format "YY : MM : DD : HH : mm : ss" ex . 1yr 2months 3days 4hrs 5mins 6sec will be specified as

> 1:2:3:4:5:6

From this value , i have to convert the duration into seconds. I want to know whether there is any inbuilt java class to specify time duration in this format?

Comment: use SimpleDateFormate and then convert date to seconds

Comment: @SanjayRabari Seconds counted from when? Date specifies point of time, not length (for length we need two points). I am not saying that your general idea is bad, but you need to be more specific :)

Comment: @Pshemo ya u right..I assumed he have to instance for that

Comment: This has nothing to do with date.I just want to specify time duration in this format .If the user gives time as 0:0:0:0:1:0 it means 1minute and i want to convert it into 60 seconds.

Comment: How many days you count in one month?

Comment: It doesn't even seem possible. How many days does a month have? 28, 30, 31? If you want an approximate value, I would just split the string and multiply the values and assume that month has 30 days and a year 365.

Comment: @Magnilex I believe it's about 30.5 days per month ;)

Comment: @Magnilex ya u r right ..i didn't think abt that.!

Comment: excluding the variables year and month is there any other way to specify duration in Days:hours:mins:secs format??

Comment: I guess you can mention starting date timestamp with respect to which year, month etc. will be calculated

Comment: One of helper class is `TimeUnit`. You can split your `day:hour:minute:second` string by `:`, parse each part to integer and sum values like `TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(numberOfDays)`.

Comment: For just days, hours, minutes and seconds use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). If you need months and years too, one place to look is [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) from [ThreeTen Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/index.html), classes developed alongside java.time.

Answer (score 1):

The [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a string representation for a span of time as `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates the date portion from the time portion.

For example, "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".

An hour and a half would be `PT1H30M`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library has the Period class that both parses and generates that format by default.

Search StackOverflow for more.

Answer (score 0):

Java-8 introduced [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and [`java.time.Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html) but there has been a long wait for a type combining period and duration as specified at [ISO_8601#Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

However, `javax.xml.datatype.Duration` has been there since Java-6 and we can use this to achieve what you want to. The assumption is that your text is always in the format, `y:M:d:H:m:s` e.g. `1:2:3:4:5:6`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        String[] durationParts = "1:2:3:4:5:6".split(":");
        char[] symbols = "YMDHMS".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("P");
        for (int i = 0; i < durationParts.length; i++) {
            sb.append(durationParts[i]).append(symbols[i]);
            if (i == 2) {
                sb.append("T");
            }
        }

        String strIso8601Duration = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(strIso8601Duration);

        Duration duration = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration(strIso8601Duration);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration.getTimeInMillis(calendar));
        System.out.println(seconds);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S
36907506
```